# How to get the current ASP.NET core controller method name inside the controller using Reflection or another accurate method

Tags: c#, reflection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to get the current method name of my `ASP.NET Core` controller

I have tried getting the method name through reflection:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProcess(int catId)
    {
        string methodName = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name;
```

but this gives me a value of `MoveNext` and not `CreateProcess`

Take note I don't want to use the ViewContext

```
string methodName = ActionContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString();
```

as I lowercase my urls via the startup settings.The above will get me `createprocess` instead of `CreateProcess`

I preferably want an easy one-liner and not a multiline extension method.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the fact that it is not just any method but a controller and use `ActionContext.ActionDescriptor.Name` property to get the action name

UPDATE: (thanks to Jim Aho)

Recent versions work with -

```
ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName
```

Comment: @JimAho what version of asp .net you're using?

Comment: @JimAho and you get an error or exception? I've checked and successfully used it

Comment: I can't even write that bit of code without getting a compilation error. `ActionContext` is a class and not a propery when trying to access it inside an action.

Answer (score 14):

In ASP.NET Core it seems to have changed and you have to use the `ActionName` property

```
((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor)ViewContext.ActionDescriptor).ActionName;
```

Answer (score 4):

The C# 5.0 CallerMemberName attribute may do the trick. 
(I haven't tested this from an async method; it works from a regular call)

```
private static string GetCallerMemberName([CallerMemberName]string name = "")
{
    return name;
}
```

Then call it from your code:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateProcess(int catId)
{
    string methodName = GetCallerMemberName();
```

Note that you don't need to pass anything to the method.

Comment: 7-1/2 years later and this solution still works great. The cleanest and easiest.

Answer (score 0):

Use the StackTrace class snd its GetFrames until you find the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by `base.ControllerContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName`

This works in .NET Core 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

modifying dfmetro above solutions works for me

```
((Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActionDescriptor)ViewContext.ActionDescriptor).ControllerName;
```

use .ControllerName to get the controller name.

> not enough reputation to comment that's why i make i post.