# .net core 2.2 get action and controller name in logging middleware without ControllerContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

I am writing a middleware in .net core 2.2. I want to get name of Action and Controller name in the middleware.
I can not use `ControllerContext` because it not available at that time.
Here is solution in core 3.1 [Read Controller and Action name in middleware .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45920870/read-controller-and-action-name-in-middleware-net-core)

```
    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        await LogRequest(context);
        await LogResponse(context);
    }

    private async Task LogResponse(HttpContext context)
    {
          ServiceName = context ...
    }
```

Comment: The HTTPContext is HTML tagged text data.  You would have to get parse the HTML to get tag names.  The tag names may not match the controller name.

Comment: what is your purpose? do you really need to ***pre-route*** for the controller & action info? I mean if you place the code ***after*** `await next ..`, you may have a better chance to get such info, especially with a combination with filters. Trying to obtain such info ***before*** reaching the MVC middleware is very hard, a lot of logic put in MVC middleware and you almost need that same logic to get the desired info. For non-attributed routes, it is easier, but for attributed routes it is very complicated.

Comment: @KingKing after searching on internet I came to know that for controller/action related login it is better to use action filters. I had a classic asp.net filters which I have used modifying that take the help of chunk reading and recyclable memory uses.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using .net core 2.2,you can only get path and get controller name and action name from it:

```
var RouteData = context.Request.Path.Value.Split("/");
var controllerName=RouteData[1];
var ActionName=RouteData[2];
```

If you have area,you need to use:

```
var RouteData = context.Request.Path.Value.Split("/");
    var controllerName=RouteData[2];
    var ActionName=RouteData[3];
```

After .net core 3.0,you can use [HttpRequest.RouteValues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.routevalues?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

```
string actionName = context.Request.RouteValues["action"].ToString();
string controllerName = context.Request.RouteValues["controller"].ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks I know this approach but if the URL is uniform than you can say this. Means if the `Request.Path` is like `stuent/studentinfo/studentname/10`